# ExceptionInInitializerError in Android app?

Tags: android, android-webview, google-sheets-api

In my Android app the WebView activity class has following line,

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "Android");
```

And in JSInterface class, I'm initializing Google "SpreadSheetService" like below,

```
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;

--- some more imports ---


public class JSInterface {
    Context mContext;

    public SpreadsheetService service;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JSInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        service = new SpreadsheetService("List Demo");
    }

    ------- some more code -----
```

When I run the application I'm getting the following exception,

```
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

which has the below trace

```
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at com.android.quotes.JSInterface.<init>(JSInterface.java:33)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at com.android.quotes.CHQuotesActivity.onCreate(CHQuotesActivity.java:19)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 21:38:00.652: E/AndroidRuntime(4085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

I searched Google, but didnt get any solution for this.. Any idea on why I'm getting this exception??

Peter

Comment: Is it possible you create an asyncTask/Handler anywhere in the code?

Comment: Seems the **trace** shows only where the `exception` is happening at. But does not show what it is causing it, from the exception find this line `Caused by:`. Check the line which causes the error.

Answer (score 17):

[Based on this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable. Check your code has any static initialization logic.

Comment: Yeah, but what could be the problem?  A static member should have no issues being accessed, hence it is static.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: It is not due to being accessed, it is because of value being initialized is not properly constructed. The right side part of static variable.

Comment: Interesting, initialized to what?  An inconvertible type or null?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: My guess is, some class instance, which is either throwing exception (or) causing some bad dependency.

Comment: I am using a library in my app. For specific class in that library, whenever I create a new instance of it, my app crashes and gives me the same exception. Since it is a library class, it means I cannot change any thing in it. At the same time, I want to use it is functionality inside that class's methods. I am totally stuck and cannto find a way to solve this, any suggestions ? thanks

Comment: @Suda.nese I would suggest create new question and refer this question, you could get lot of answers.

Comment: @Nambari :  I've already done so here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/42227184/2135363 .. and here :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/42248119/2135363 .. Please have a look.

Comment: @McLan did you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: @user158 can’t remember. But will check for you.

Answer (score 2):

**java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError android OS 11**

if this is related to OkHttp then update your version 4.4.0.

In this version its fixed.

**implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0'**

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your android version is 11 or higher you might encounter `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` and `IllegalStateException` for which you will need to add latest okhttp3 dependencies which are:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange! But let me share my experience, maybe it can help someone!

Was working on an Android app that was previously being run without any issues.
After I rest my Android device and on the first install of App after the reset. I
got this exception `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

1. I uninstalled the app
2. Cleaned the project
3. Rebuild the project

After that when I ran the app the exception was gone.

I don't know what happened, but the above steps just solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ExceptionInInitializerError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) (***updated link***) shows that an `unexpected exception` has occurred in a **static initializer**. Literally, if this `exception` is shown, one should understand that Java has failed to do evaluation on **static initializer block** or on instantiation of a **static variable**.

Anyways, each moment **static initializer** encounters an `exception` its automatically wrapped into an instance of `ExceptionInInitializerError` class. In such a way it keeps a reference to the actual `exception` as the root cause.

On my situation, using below exception trace:

```
   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.fole_Studios.sup.database.DBqueries.getAllUniversities(DBqueries.java:581)
        at com.fole_Studios.sup.RegisterFragment.universityDataList(RegisterFragment.java:216)
         ...............
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.fole_Studios.sup.database.DBqueries.<clinit>(DBqueries.java:80)
```

I referred directly from what caused the error from `Caused by:`. Hence, I discovered that I am instantiating a **static variable** which has a `null` value. I solved it and everything was working perfect.