# fragment not working properly in lower versions of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using fragment in my project the single fragment class is called in all other classes of the project.Now the problem is my app runs only in lollipop device and it stops at lower versions of android.I have attached the error message below. As a Beginner I have tried my best but I can't find the right solution. Need your help friends.Suggest some possible solution to solve it.

Errors shown while running in lower versions of android

```
09-16 14:57:40.976  13600-13604/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 354K, 28% free 6018K/8344K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 37ms
09-16 14:57:42.218  13600-13600/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2135)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.ContainerHelpers
            at android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap.<init>(SimpleArrayMap.java:209)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.<clinit>(Fragment.java:169)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2135)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my fragment xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/adview153613"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/aagr_background2">

    <ImageView        
              android:id="@+id/addviewimage"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"                    
              android:src="@drawable/adview1536132" />        

      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="-----------------"
         />
       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/addviewimage1"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/fwh"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/fwh"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
          android:src="@drawable/close" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which version are you trying?

Comment: now am running in jelly bean version

Comment: check your manifest if android:minSdkVersion supports current version

Comment: yes i have checked it no wrong in that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8929660/3640637

Comment: I think my issue is different

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have updated the SDK Tools but not SDK build tools. Try updating SDK Build tools then restart the IDE then try again.

Comment: Thank you Neeraj kumar.can u tell me how to do that as a beginner am no aware of it

Comment: In android Studio : go to Tools(Menu at top) -> Android -> SDK Manager

Comment: i got it now its updating .

Comment: @Neeran kumar are u sure that is the only problem for this issue